# Aggregation to combine collections attempt

Tags: java, mongodb, join

I want to perform an aggregation in Java: here's my attempt

**Example of dept collection.**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4dc8635dd32dbcba4ae0ae"),
    "name" : "Sales"
}
```

**Example of employee_dept collection**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5411be6cd7524f36a7933f"),
    "dept_id" : ObjectId("5d4dc8635dd32dbcba4ae0ae"),
    "employee_id" : ObjectId("5d4dc8635dd32dbcba4ae0af")
}
```

**Example of output expected**

```
{
    "_id" :"5d4dc8635dd32dbcba4ae0ae",
    "name" : "Sales"
}
```

**Java code**

```
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("employee_id", "5d4dc8635dd32dbcba4ae0af"));

// build the $lookup operations
DBObject lookupFields = new BasicDBObject("from", "dept");
lookupFields.put("localField", "dept_id");
lookupFields.put("foreignField", "_id");
lookupFields.put("as", "dept");
DBObject lookup = new BasicDBObject("$lookup", lookupFields);

// build the $projection operations
DBObject projectFields = new BasicDBObject("name", 1);
projectFields.put("_id", 1);
DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", projectFields);

List<DBObject> pipeline = Arrays.asList(match, lookup, project);

AggregateIterable aggregateIterable = dbCollection.aggregate(pipeline);

for(Object result: aggregateIterable) {
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

**Issue:** aggregateIterable is not getting output due to some reason

B) if you don't mind adding how to project for $employee_dept._id and employee_id within the following?

```
Document project = new Document("$project", new BasicDBObject("name", "$dept.name")
            .append("e_id", "$employee_department._id")
            .append("employee_id", "$employee_department.employee_id")
            .append("dept_id", "$dept._id"));
```

Comment: ObjectId is a 24 character hexadecimal string. Please post valid data.

Comment: edited examples.

Comment: any idea on what's wrong in here, how to access the record if query is ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issues:**

- The comparison of employee_id of type ObjectId with a string
- In projection, the name and _id are inside 'dept' array and not at
  the root level

**Fixed code:**

```
Document match = new Document("$match", new Document("employee_id", new ObjectId("5d4dc8635dd32dbcba4ae0af")));

// build the $lookup operations
Document lookupFields = new Document("from", "dept");
lookupFields.put("localField", "dept_id");
lookupFields.put("foreignField", "_id");
lookupFields.put("as", "dept");
Document lookup = new Document("$lookup", lookupFields);

// build unwind operation
Document unwind = new Document("$unwind", "$dept");

// build the $projection operations
Document projectFields = new Document("name", "$dept.name");
projectFields.put("_id", new Document("$toString", "$dept._id"));
Document project = new Document("$project", projectFields);

List<Document> pipeline = Arrays.asList(match, lookup, unwind, project);

AggregateIterable<Document> aggregateIterable = groupDAO.database.getCollection("employee_dept")
        .aggregate(pipeline);

for (Document result : aggregateIterable) {
    System.out.println(result.toJson());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I check from `AggregateIterable` that a record was found? last 3 lines from my code please. It's going to be one record result only.

Comment: also how do I output `name` and `_id` fields from `AggregateIterable`?

Comment: @AppDeveloper The new mongo java driver doesn't support BasicDBObject in the aggregate method. Would update my answer accordingly. Which version are you using?

Comment: Ok. See the output you want in JSON is not possible as JSON doesn't support ObjectId. We can get output like this: ```{ "_id" : "5d4dc8635dd32dbcba4ae0ae", "name" : "Sales" }```

Comment: sure, that's fine, fixing my expected output, i just want to output name and id separately.

Comment: Okay. Updating answer accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197954/discussion-between-mrssharma-and-appdeveloper).

Comment: is there a property like `count` on `aggregateIterable` so I can check if record exists?

Comment: see section (B) please